# SignalR and failed websocket connection, but still works

Tags: websocket, signalr

I am currently getting this error below in Chrome console, but it still connects successfully with SignalR.  Any reason why I am getting this error?

JS Hub Connection

```
scheduleHub = $.connection.scheduleHub;
        scheduleHub.client.viewing = function (name, message) {
            app.showWarning(message, name, function () {
                app.refreshHash();
            });
        };

        if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
            $.connection.hub.qs = { "eventid": options.eventId };
            $.connection.hub.start()
                .done(function () {
                    alert('Connected');
                    //scheduleHub.server.viewing('wow', 'test');
                })
                .fail(function() { alert('Could not Connect!'); });
        }
```

**Chrome Console**

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:2222/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&eventid=23919&connectionToken=CV3wchrj88t6FdjgA%2BREdzEDIw0rhW6r2aUrb%2BI8qInsb3Y9BqQSOscPxfAZ2g0Dxl704usqdBBn%2BNSFKpjVNOtwASndOweD1kGWPCkWEbtJBMu%2B&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22schedulehub%22%7D%5D&tid=5' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

[image]

Comment: Which operating system are you using as server? You need Windows 8 or 2012 to use websockets.

Comment: it should be fine, can you enable logging in SignalR and see what is the error?

Comment: It is weird because it is even failing to connect SSE, did you have a chance to try to find the exception that is causing the HTTP 500 Internal Server Error ?

Answer (score 6):

Web Sockets initially starts by negotiating the websockets connection over HTTP. During this HTTP handshake, the web server probably raised an exception, anyway, it returns HTTP Status Code 500. Without a successful HTTP response, Chrome is unable to continue negotiating the web sockets connection.

Since SignalR works over multiple transports, and not just websockets, once websockets connection failed, it will have automatically have switched to try some other transport, like forever frame or polling, which is why your connection still works.

Comment: Chrome is not the problem, the web server is where the error originates.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the console

Comment: As I said before... your console is just saying your web *server* is returning an error. Did you try debugging your server yet?

Comment: How can I debug my server when it works on my server after the error is thrown??  The server works fine.

Comment: Have you tried telling your debugger (attached to server) to break even on handled exceptions that aren't in your code?
Or you could turn on error details in faults, send a websockets looking request to the URL in question, and look at the response you get